# VS 2013 c# sqlite build fails App Certification Kit high risk from msvcr100.dll

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

I get a failure from the App certifictaion kit testing my app, which is developed for the WinRT (ARM) Platform.

I use the `SQLite for WindowsRT` lib and therefor the `Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Runtime Package`.

The Cert Kit sauy that 
`msvcr100.dll has a high risk for the user`
and I have to set the following Linker options 
`SAFESHEH, DYNIMCBASE; NXCOMPAT and APPCONTAINER`

It has something to do with the `msvcr100.dll`

However after 1h of googleing I was not able to find how to set this flags in Visual Studio 2013 c# Windows App project.

Anybody could guide me through this, it is really driving me n**** :-D
Thanks in advance.

****EDIT SOLUTION ****
http://www.lyalin.com/2013/07/09/sqlite-for-windows-runtime-for-windows-8-1-apps/
This did the trick. Removed the lib from my nuget manager and downloaded it directly from the sqlite site did the trick. Now it is working with a new c++ lib

Thanks guys

Comment: `msvcr100.dll` is the Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime for Visual Studio 2010. I think you need to have `msvcr110.dll` or `msvcr120.dll` (more likely the latter for a Windows 8.1 app). Maybe one of your other references has it erroneously?

Comment: yeah an update to the version directly from sqlite did the trick! http://www.lyalin.com/2013/07/09/sqlite-for-windows-runtime-for-windows-8-1-apps/

Comment: Sry, corrected it. @Hans Passant, aren't you able to edit this post?

Comment: Ok, will keep that in mind...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in [this blog](http://www.lyalin.com/2013/07/09/sqlite-for-windows-runtime-for-windows-8-1-apps/)  the trick is to update to a beta release of sqlite.
Therefore I had to remove the lib from my nuget manager and downloaded it directly from the sqlite site. 
This version is requiring a new c++ runtime version and this version passes the certification kit.

DO NOT USE SQLITE FROM NUGET PACKAGE MANAGER!